# Null-terminated strings created with calloc?

Tags: c, string, pointers, calloc, nul

I want to allocate memory for a string using calloc, I know that calloc fills the whole allocated memory with 0, but I also found out that they are different from \0 in some contexts.
This whole discussion it's kind of confusing for a newbie (like myself), so I was wondering if anyone could give me the final answer, if I use alloc to initialize a string do I have to manually set the last character to "\0" or not?

Comment: calloc zero initializes the allocated memory. and '\0' is zero.:)

Comment: The literal character `'\0'` is actually the octal escape for `0`. So the null terminator `'\0'` is really zero.

Comment: The major thing to remember when allocating memory for strings is to actually include the space for the terminator.

Comment: Thanks y'all for the quick answers!

Comment: There are a couple ways this can go wrong. 1) you allocate 5 bytes with `calloc` and then put a 5 character string into that memory (e.g. "hello"). That won't work, because "hello" needs 6 bytes, 5 for the letters and one more for the `'\0'` at the end. 2) you allocate 6 or more bytes, put "hello" into the memory, and then later attempt to change the string to "hi". That won't work unless there's a `'\0'` after the `i`. Without the `'\0'`, you get "hillo".

Comment: @user3386109 I see, it sure is a helpful reminder the second one, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between integral value `0`, with which `calloc` fills up the allocated memory, and literal character `'\0'`, which is identical to integral value `0`.

So if you write up to `n-1` characters to a memory block of `n` characters  allocated with `calloc`, you will always have a valid 0-terminated string.